# Specifying order for "Special" products widget in the homepage

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, magento1.9.3

I have an installation of Magento 1.9, where I have set a widget as "Catalog Sale Prduct List". This can be just done on:

***CMS->Widgets->Add New Widget Instance***

And then, assigning the type ***Catalog Sale Prduct List*** o the new widget.

Now, I need then to come in an specific order, and can not see what  Magento is using to sot them. I can tell that if I modify them the products in the admin, the order of the display of this list changes, in a kind of "random" order.

Does someone know how they are actually ordered? I can not see any option in the admin to affect that.

Or, does someone know where is the query that fetch this, so I could just sort it there?

Any other suggestion?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I'm maybe wrong but I can not find the "Catalog Sale Prduct List" or "Catalog Sale Product List" widget in a 1.9.3 version.

So, I guess you have a third part extension that adds this widget type and you will have to look in its source code to understand how the products are ordered.